# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 availability on MSDN

Tags: visual-studio, msdn, visual-studio-2017

I understand VS 2017 will be launched on March 7th. Any idea if it'll be available on MSDN sooner? I did some research but couldn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download Visual Studio 2017 RC at

https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_Enterprise.exe

they give you trail for 90 days with out activation code.

Comment: At this point, I wouldn't want to install the RC version. I don't want to have to upgrade it to final version in less than a month. Worst case, I'll have to wait till March 7th.